Image uploads are limited to 50 megapixels; please use a smaller image
Trying to upload image (190 KB size, 800*800 pixels) but getting error:

Image uploads are limited to 50 megapixels; please use a smaller image



Possibly related:  SO's image hosting does not support GIFs.

That has to be the first time I've seen an image upload feature validate in terms of megapixels. I guess they now assume screenshots come from a phone?

@AnonCoward That's not true. They didn't support it for teams 6 years ago, but they certainly support it now for the main site, even though there were bugs at some point

While the size is only 800x800, that animation contains 129 frames - so there are 82,560,000 separate pixels if you consider each pixel across the dimensions of x, y, and time.
(It's entirely possible that the limit isn't worked out in that way, but it's a plausible way of interpreting the limit. You might want to try with an animated gif of size 800x800 but only 70 frames, for example.)

If the limit is in size*frames, I'm fairly certain I've uploaded GIFs with a sum total of pixels much more than 800x800 * 129 frames in the past (pre-new uploader) and they weren't limited in such fashion. So, at the very least this would be inconsistent with the old uploader behaviour.

That appears to be right, see this answer on a bug report. A megapixel limit appears to be in place for GIFs specifically, and since the 17th of June, so that aligns with it working in the past.

Good to see a 6 year old bug/planned feature is still a bug/planned feature. Don't change any time soon Stack Overflow, that's the part we "love" about you... Oh, wait.
